# C# Initializing form upon default text

Tags: c#

I have **Form 1**  With a label that has been set to *"Company Name"* by default.

```
CompanyNameLBL.Text
```

I placed a timer here so that if the database is not setup, then initialize Database Setup.

```
if (CompanyNameLBL.Text == "Company Name")
        {
            //Instantiating Timer Class
            databaseTimer.Interval = 2000; // 1000 milliseconds
            databaseTimer.Enabled = true;
            databaseTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dbTimer);
        }

    protected void dbTimer(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        databaseTimer.Stop();
        DatabaseSetup setupDatabase = new DatabaseSetup();
        this.Hide();
        setupDatabase.Show();
    }
```

I have **Form 2**, which is my Database Setup. Once entering the right credentials, I can change the name of the label like this:

```
            formLogin loginScreen = new formLogin();
            loginScreen.CompanyNameLBL.Text = "a new company name";
            loginScreen.Show();
```

It changes the label, but my timer still goes off. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
formLogin loginScreen = new formLogin();
```

You are creating a *new* `formLogin` instance, not a reference to the existing instance.  You need to figure out how to communicate between the two forms.  One option is to make the result of the login a property of the `DatabaseSetup` form, then pull *that* after closing the form:

```
    databaseTimer.Stop();
    DatabaseSetup setupDatabase = new DatabaseSetup();
    this.Hide();
    setupDatabase.Show();
    loginScreen.CompanyNameLBL.Text = setupDatabase.CompanyName;  // new property
    this.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply used

```
public formLogin(string dbName)
```

and passed it through that variable.